# Selenium IDE 1.8.1 and Firefox 3

Tags: selenium-ide, firefox-3

Is Selenium IDE 1.8.1 compatible with Firefox 3.x.y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the Selenium IDE 1.8.1 but Selenium IDE 1.8.0 requires Firefox 3.5 or later, [see](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Selenium-IDE.shtml). Also, [see](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes) these release notes about it. Additionally, when Firefox 13 is available today, you should use higher versions of Firefox.

Comment: Yes Lion, I do agree with you: FF 13 or higher version should be used

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE 1.8.1 is not compatible with Firefox 3 (I am using FF 3.6.18). Selenium IDE 1.7.2 is compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE 1.8.1 is not compatible with Firefox 3.5

Selenium IDE 1.8.1 is available for higher version of FF.

Comment: The latest version of Selenium IDE is 1.9.1 most probably